# 3d Letters using pure CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create a 3d text effect like this using pure css?

[image]

The best I could do was this:

[image]

I want the effect / shadow to come behind the text in a linear fashion.

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/css-3d-isometric-text-forked-vbg10g?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: This is done with multiple shadows. See [Is there a way to make a 3D-text effect with JavaScript/CSS](/q/52030966/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

text 3d using css only ,for this try below, please comment if any query

```css
body {
            background: green;
        }
 
        
 
        h1 {
          color: white;
            font-size: 8em;
            transition: 0.5s;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #ccc,
                0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 4px 0 #ccc,
                0 5px 0 #ccc, 0 6px 0 #ccc,
                0 7px 0 #ccc, 0 8px 0 #ccc,
                0 9px 0 #ccc, 0 10px 0 #ccc,
                0 11px 0 #ccc, 0 12px 0 #ccc,
                0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
```

```html
<h1>Hi Stackoverflow</h1>
```